# .Net 3.5 to 4 Migration resulting in Application Slowdown

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

As I wanted to benefit from new multicore threading improvements from .Net Framework 4, I recompiled all of my solution projects from 3.5 to 4.Everything compiled Ok.
But what was my surprise to see that my application runs much slower when compiled in .Net 4 compared to 3.5. I was not expecting that at all. It is a scientific processing App, so computing time is what it's all about.
I have no clue where to start from, and for the time being, and I prefer to think that I have missed something during the migration process, that is fixable, rather than the App is "*per se*" running slower in .4 (can't see any logical reason for that...)

Any Ideas are Welcome

Comment: Please also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762663/compiled-program-runs-much-slower-after-i-switched-to-vs-2010

Comment: Can you describe at a very high level what your code is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a profiler on both versions and compare the results. It might give you a starting point

Comment: Oh God... Guess I'll have to spend another afternoon surfing on techCrunch waiting for Analysis Report to generate... :-(

Comment: Just in case you don't already have a profiler, take a look at [redgates Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). It has a 14 days trial and a very nice and easy user interface to find the *hot path*.

Comment: @Oliver: Sorry but I'm broke since I've traded a ball-breaking psychic Boss and a boring but secure job in a bank for an unprofitable and risky but intellectually-challenging self-employing business :-D

Comment: A 14 day trial doesn't cost a dime ;)

Answer (score 3):

here's a small checklist for you:

1. Check, if you are using a Release Build - maybe you've done a
   Debug Build
2. Check, if all performance optimizations are turned on in the
   project file.
3. Check your target platform, if it maybe is set to x86.
4. Did you change your code? Compare both versions, if there are
   significant differences? e.g. are
   you using Linq?
5. Go and get a Profiler for testing. I would recommend ReSharper
   dotTrace.

Hope that I could help you

Comment: I went through all steps... I'm presently patiently staring at the profiler like a cat in front of a fishbowl, as step 5 is my last long-road hope.

Comment: Have a look at the LinQ Statements, if you have some. This would be a first place to look at. Additionally use Dictionary instead of Lists for lookups.